# Proving a function is continuous using sequential criteria

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

> Let $X=\{0\} \cup\left\{\frac 1n \colon n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$ with subspace topology of $\mathbb R$. Define $f \colon X \to X$ as $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{n+1},&\text{ if }x=\frac 1n\\0,&\text{ if }x=0\end{cases}$$
>   Show $f$ is continuous.

**My attempt:**

Let $U$ be open in $X.$

**Case 1:** $0 \not\in U.$ Then $$U=\bigcup_i\left\{\frac{1}{n_i}\right\}$$ where the union might be finite or infinite. Then $$f^{-1}(U)=\bigcup_i\left\{\frac{1}{n_i-1}\right\}$$ which is open.

**Case 2:** $0 \in U$. Then $$U=\{0\}\cup\bigcup_i\left\{\frac{1}{n_i}\right\}$$ where the union might be finite or infinite. Then $$f^{-1}(U)=\{0\}\cup\bigcup_i\left\{\frac{1}{n_i-1}\right\}$$ which is open.

Thus, $f$ is continuous.

> I want to know if there is a way to prove it using sequential criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $x_n \to x$ with $x_n,x \in X$.

Then either $x=0$ or $x={1 \over m}$ for some $m$. In the latter case
you must have $x_n = x$ after a finite number of indices and so $f(x_n) \to f(x)$.

If $x=0$ then note that $0 \le f(x_n) \le x_n$ and hence $f(x_n) \to 0 = f(x)$.